# Arrays.sort(Object[] a) - how is it implemented?

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

Are there any resources on how the mergeSort used by Arrays.sort(Object[] a) is implemented? While it is documented quite good, I have a hard time understanding it (especially why the src and dest are are switched when mergeSort() get's recursively called).

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html here's the source code

Comment: Bozho, you should have posted that an an answer!

Comment: Looks like the real work starts on line 486.

Comment: @Will, yes, maybe. there it goes.

Comment: Isn't JDK7 going to have Tim Sort or a dual-pivot Quicksort or something?

Comment: @Tom Hawtin Yes, I believe it will have both timsort and a dual-pivot quicksort. The dual-pivot quicksort will only be to sort arrays of primitives because it is an unstable sort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here is the source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html) of `java.util.Arrays`.

Actually, you have that source code in the JDK - just open `java.util.Arrays` in your IDE and the source code + the comments will appear. If you don't have an IDE, look at `JDK_HOME\src.zip`

Then, put it in your IDE and trace how it works.

- put breakpoints (and run a program in debug mode)
- use `System.out.println(..)`
- change parts of it to see how they are reflected.
- read the [wikipedia article about merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
- pay attention to this comment: `// Recursively sort halves of dest into src`

Comment: It **appears** the OP already saw the source (since s/he mentions the fact that the `src` and `dest` arrays are switched when recursively called) but has a hard time understanding the logic.

Comment: hm, yes. I gave some pointers on how to understand it better.

Comment: I could be wrong of course... Anyway, I was going to suggest the OP to use the *poor-man's debugger* (putting some System.out.println's in the algorithm), but you beat me to it!

Comment: :) it was in the original answer, but wasn't that much pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know the sources were available in src.zip. I only read the class file which Eclipse opened but which I wasn't able to debug (which makes sense ^^). But with the source, I was able to modify the code, put in some breakpoints and finally realized how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I ever had the same confusion with you. According to my understanding, the reason for this switching is very simple - make followed merging step easier. No magic.

```
    private static void mergeSortWithoutSwitch(Object[] src, Object[] dest, int low, int high, int off) {
    int length = high - low;

    // Insertion sort on smallest arrays
    if (length < INSERTIONSORT_THRESHOLD) {
        for (int i = low; i < high; i++)
            for (int j = i; j > low && ((Comparable) dest[j - 1]).compareTo(dest[j]) > 0; j--)
                swap(dest, j, j - 1);
        return;
    }

    // Recursively sort halves of dest into src
    int destLow = low;
    int destHigh = high;
    low += off;
    high += off;
    int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
    mergeSortWithoutSwitch(src, dest, low, mid, off);
    mergeSortWithoutSwitch(src, dest, mid, high, off);

    // If list is already sorted, just copy from src to dest. This is an
    // optimization that results in faster sorts for nearly ordered lists.
    if (((Comparable) dest[mid - 1]).compareTo(dest[mid]) <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Merge sorted halves (now in src) into dest
    for (int i = destLow, p = low, q = mid; i < destHigh; i++) {
        if (q >= high || p < mid && ((Comparable) dest[p]).compareTo(dest[q]) <= 0)
            src[i] = dest[p++];
        else
            src[i] = dest[q++];
    }

    // copy back
    for (int i = destLow; i < destHigh; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[i];
    }

}
```

Above is the implementation without switching, from the code, you can see we need one more step in merging - copy back. I think the parameter naming in mergeSort is a little confused, since the src is auxiliary array which is only used in merging step, it will be better to name it with aux (We can even remove it from method signature, and create a local variable when merging). And dest is the result array.